# PHPのPDOStatement::executeが失敗したとき、Falseを返すのかExceptionを投げるのか

Tags: php, pdo

`PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`のとき、

```
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM po");
    $result= $stmt->execute();
    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception ("execute_false");
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

とすると、
`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hoge_table.po' doesn't exist`
となり、`execute()`が`false`ではなく例外を投げているような気がします。

しかし、[ドキュメント](http://php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.execute.php)を見ても、executeが例外を出すという記述はありません。たとえば[prepare](http://php.net/manual/ja/pdo.prepare.php)のところには例外を吐くと書かれています。

これについて、`execute`が例外を出したのではなく、`prepare`の例外が
`execute`の実行により起こり、`execute`が例外を出したように見える、という解釈で正しいのでしょうか？

また、`execute`自身が`false`を返す失敗とはどのようなものなのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` が設定されるとexecute();でのエラーもPDOExceptionがなげられます。

`$stmt->execute();` が`false`を返す失敗は、SQLの文法に誤りが有る時と
`?`が指定されたが 渡すパラメータが指定されなかった時です。

**falseを返す例、文法に誤り**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("wSELECT * FROM test where test = ?");
$stmt->execute(array('test1'));
```

**渡すパラメータが指定されなかった**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test where test = ?");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: なるほどてす、やっぱりexecuteは例外を投げるんですね。ドキュメントが誤りということでしょうか？

Comment: newで作られたPDOオブジェクト全体へのエラーモード指定なので配下のメソッドも同じ動作になります。